# Is ForceClose a part of the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: support, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this a Stack Exchange website?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40784/is-this-a-stack-exchange-website)

I found an answer to something I was looking for, using Google and found this site: http://www.forceclose.com/

Is this a legit part of the StackExchange network? I tried to log in with same openid, but it says it has not seen that openid before.

Comment: strange name for an android Q&A site..

Comment: it gave me the answer to my question asking about forcing to close startup processes for android. I can see it being a good site. But I don't trust it if it's not part of the stackexchange network.

Comment: It's an older stack exchange V1.0 site.  It is built on the same (but older) platform, but that service was shut down a year ago and these sties are slowly being turned off in favor of the community-built area51 process. So it is a part of the old network, but not an official stack exchange 2.0 site.

Comment: Feel free to check out [Android.SE] if you want a better site that's part of the SE network :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may view-source it

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

Comment: ...Which means it's an old SE 1.0 site, and not really a part of the latest network.

Answer (score 0):

I found the full list of stackexcahnge sites that are legitimately part of the network:
https://stackexchange.com/sites

ForceClose is not on that list. Hence, it is not a legitimate part of the network.